# In this concrete example of applying sklearn knn (with kd_tree) on Iris Data Set, how many partitions are there?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, partitioning

The [k-nearest neighbors algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (k-NN)

> is a
>   non-parametric method used for classification and regression. In both
>   cases, the input consists of the k closest training examples in the
>   feature space.

[sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) provides an option `kd_tree` for `algorithm` parameter

```
class sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights=’uniform’, algorithm=’auto’, leaf_size=30, p=2, metric=’minkowski’, metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, **kwargs)
```

A [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) (short for k-dimensional tree) is a space-partitioning data structure for organizing points in a k-dimensional space.

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> iris.data.shape
(150, 4)
```

In this concrete example of applying sklearn knn (with kd_tree) on [Iris Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris), how many partitions are there?

Answer (score 0):

Four.  See a notebook at https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/CV423485.ipynb

In general, we have a guarantee that each leaf node will be between `leaf_size` and `2*leaf_size` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree), so we were certain to have between $\lceil 150/60\rceil=3$ and $\lfloor 150/30\rfloor=5$ leaves.